# Left shift with condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv, data-science

I have some problems with a csv file, I have tried several solutions through the pandas library but none has worked for me, I want to make a left shift to 3 columns in case that in one of them appears a certain code (in this case 11 or 22), for example, this would be my input:

| code | name | % | code 2 | name 2 | % 2 | code 3 | name 3 | % 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | John | 34 | 44 | Rob | 23 | 33 | Peter | 15 |
| 22 | Ken | 45 | 33 | Peter | 45 | 44 | Rob | 25 |
| 33 | Peter | 34 | 66 | Abraham | 37 | 77 | Harry | 67 |
| 11 | John | 45 | 77 | Harry | 39 | 88 | Mary | 20 |

And I expect something like this:

| code | name | % | code 2 | name 2 | % 2 | code 3 | name 3 | % 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | Rob | 23 | 33 | Peter | 15 |  |  |  |
| 33 | Peter | 45 | 44 | Rob | 25 |  |  |  |
| 33 | Peter | 34 | 66 | Abraham | 37 | 77 | Harry | 67 |
| 77 | Harry | 39 | 88 | Mary | 20 |  |  |  |

any idea how I could solve my problem with pandas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the above dataframes with `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: and don't name your columns something like `% 3`, that is just painful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
mask = df['code'].isin([11,22])
df.loc[mask] = df.loc[mask].shift(-3,axis=1)
```

**Output -**

```
  code   name     %  code 2   name 2   % 2  code 3 name 3   % 3
0  44.0    Rob  23.0    33.0    Peter  15.0     NaN    NaN   NaN
1  33.0  Peter  45.0    44.0      Rob  25.0     NaN    NaN   NaN
2  33.0  Peter  34.0    66.0  Abraham  37.0    77.0  Harry  67.0
3  77.0  Harry  39.0    88.0     Mary  20.0     NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: @Nk03 Good answer. instead of checking the `isin` condition two times you can check for condition once and store the result in a variable. Then you can use that variable to select the required rows.